# D3 function to wrap text fails in tabbed display

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, d3.js, svg, tabs

I am using a function borrowed from [ericsoco](https://gist.github.com/ericsoco/647db6ebadd4f4756cae) to wrap text beyond a certain width within SVG elements.  The web page has a (Bootstrap) tabbed interface to a number of SVG elements.  The text wrap function works perfectly on the first tab but not on the second.  Somehow the tab function seems to interfere with the text wrap function.

The web page is at https://manypossibilities.net/spectrum-chart/index.html 
and full source code can be found at 
https://github.com/stevesong/spectrum-chart/blob/master/index.html
and https://github.com/stevesong/spectrum-chart/blob/master/byCountry.js

You can see that the name Telecom Namibia is wrapped correctly on the first tab but not on the second.
[image: Wrapped text works in first tab but not second]

Wrap text function follows:

```
function wrap(text, width) {
    text.each(function() {
        var breakChars = ['/', '&', '-'],
            text = d3.select(this),
            textContent = text.text(),
            spanContent;
        breakChars.forEach(char => {
            // Add a space after each break char for the function to use to determine line breaks
            textContent = textContent.replace(char, char + ' ');
        });
        var words = textContent.split(/\s+/).reverse(),
            word,
            line = [],
            lineNumber = 0,
            lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
            x = text.attr('x'),
            y = text.attr('y'),
            dy = parseFloat(text.attr('dy') || 0),
            tspan = text.text(null).append('tspan').attr('x', x).attr('y', y).attr('dy', dy + 'em');
        while (word = words.pop()) {
            line.push(word);
            tspan.text(line.join(' '));
            if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
                line.pop();
                spanContent = line.join(' ');
                breakChars.forEach(char => {
                    // Remove spaces trailing breakChars that were added above
                    spanContent = spanContent.replace(char + ' ', char);
                });
                tspan.text(spanContent);
                line = [word];
                tspan = text.append('tspan').attr('x', x).attr('y', y).attr('dy', ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + 'em').text(word);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that considerable chunks of this function come from [Mike Bostock's Block on text wrapping](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321)

Comment: Ericsoco fully acknowledges forking the code from Mike Bostock and credits him. Perhaps I should have credited them both.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. It wouldn't hurt to acknowledge both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: I no longer do it as I detail below; it's too hard to keep track of the active `div` and `svg` on big projects. Instead I use this:

```
var plate;
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    plate = d3.select('body').append('svg').style('position', 'absolute')
        .style('left', '-1000px');
});
function getTextWidth (str) {
    var text = plate.append('text').text(str),
        width = text.node().getComputedTextLength();
    text.remove();
    return width;
}
```

It works by drawing the text on an svg that's hidden outside the browser window, and then removing it (which is optional). NB: any synchronous scripts will pause the DOM loading, so you should make redundancies on the creation of the plate `svg`

---

### Original answer:

I ran into a similar problem. When a tab isn't the active one, Bootstrap hides it. This means that using the `getComputedTextLength` method will return 0.

The solution? Only class each `div` as `tab-pane` *after* all the text is done drawing, or even better: after all the drawing is done. That way Bootstrap doesn't hide it until all the computations are done.

To do this, I would recommend making each of the svg containing `div`s share a class, like `holder`. Then:

```
d3.selectAll('div.holder').classed('tab-pane', true);
```

**Edit**: you will also need to remove the `fade` class before you can use `getComputedTextLength`

The way I implement this with minimal change to the code-base is by doing this:

```
var tabs = d3.selectAll('div.tab-pane').classed('tab-pane', false).classed('fade', false);
//all calls to getComputedTextLength go here
tabs.classed('tab-pane', true).classed('fade', true);
```

anywhere that I would use `getComputedTextLength`.

In your case, I'd recommend changing:

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="byCountry.js"></script>
```

To this:

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script> var tabs = d3.selectAll('div.tab-pane')
             .classed('tab-pane', false).classed('fade', false);</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="byCountry.js"></script>
<script> tabs.classed('tab-pane', true).classed('fade', true);</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I checked the values of getComputedTextLength and you're absolutely right, that is exactly what is happening.  For some reason the fix you suggest does not appear to work though.  Double-checking to make sure I have applied it correctly.

Comment: @SteveSong I've updated my answer. Let me know if it helps!

Comment: The former rather than the latter recommendation did the trick.  I had to add and remove the tab-pane classes inside the text wrap function immediately before and after the getComputedTextLength call.  The latter solution, while more elegant and efficient, did not seem to work.

Thanks so much!  I can't tell you how much I appreciate your help, especially coming back to the problem again.